# Extreme social isolation; world recovers

Tags: story-identification, ray-bradbury

Story in which everyone lives entirely within their own homes with wall-sized TV screens to let them interact with friends and family, but no one ever left the homes due to fears of pollution etc.  Finally someone (a child?) leaves and finds the worlds is clean and beautiful.

Comment: You’ve tagged this with Ray Bradbury, does that mean you think it might be one of his works? Also was this a novel, short story, etc.? Lastly when did you read/see this? Was it new at the time? You can [edit] your question to include that and any other information you may remember.

Comment: The first sentence, until "pollution," reminds me of the Solarian society in Asimov's *The Naked Sun*.

Comment: Reminds me slightly of "The Naked Sun", but they are not isolated because of pollution.

Comment: We're heading that way fast with COVAD-19...

Answer (score 32):

This sounds like "It's Such a Beautiful Day", a short story by by Isaac Asimov. As you say people never step outside their homes, instead they use teleportation devices called Doors to get directly to their destination. One day a family's Door malfunctions, and the child has to walk to the neighbor's house to use their Door to go to school. After this short walk, the first time he has ever been outdoors, he falls in love with the outside world (much to his parents' disgust).

Comment: I thought about this too, but the question explicitly says "no one ever left the homes".  You are probably right though.

Answer (score 13):

A classic story that seems to fit this description is "[The Machine Stops](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41186)", by E. M. Forster. Although this work was published in 1909, Forster described advanced technology including a communication system similar to the Internet. From the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Machine_Stops):

> The story describes a world in which most of the human population has
> lost the ability to live on the surface of the Earth. Each individual
> now lives in isolation below ground in a standard room, with all
> bodily and spiritual needs met by the omnipotent, global Machine.
> Travel is permitted, but is unpopular and rarely necessary.
> Communication is made via a kind of instant messaging/video
> conferencing machine with which people conduct their only activity:
> the sharing of ideas and what passes for knowledge.
>
> The two main characters, Vashti and her son Kuno, live on opposite
> sides of the world. Vashti is content with her life, which, like most
> inhabitants of the world, she spends producing and endlessly
> discussing secondhand 'ideas'. Kuno, however, is a sensualist and a
> rebel. He persuades a reluctant Vashti to endure the journey (and the
> resultant unwelcome personal interaction) to his room. There, he tells
> her of his disenchantment with the sanitised, mechanical world.
>
> He confides to her that he has visited the surface of the Earth
> without permission, and that he saw other humans living outside the
> world of the Machine. However, the Machine recaptures him, and he is
> threatened with 'Homelessness': expulsion from the underground
> environment and presumed death. Vashti, however, dismisses her son's
> concerns as dangerous madness and returns to her part of the world.

It seems likely, however, that several stories will match the OP's description. There is one mismatch: Vashti's son is a full-grown man.

Comment: The ending of the story is also far less harmonic than "someone leaves and finds the worlds is clean and beautiful".

Comment: _The Machine Stops_ is exactly the story that came to mind when I read this question. Such a good story and so relevant today! It's only about 50 pages long, too. The OP wasn't clear on who left - and a child can still be fully-grown. @MichaelBorgwardt is right, though - the ending doesn't quite fit.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt Her son does indeed find that the world is clean and beautiful.  What happens when the Machine stops (it's not exactly a spoiler, considering it's the title!) is another matter, sure, but that's later on.

Comment: The full text of the story is available [here](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Machine_Stops).

Answer (score 1):

This may be referring to the Ray Bradbury story “Jack in the Box” which is about a boy raised in seclusion by his mother.  He thinks his large home is the entire world.  Mom dies near the end and the boy escapes the house, saying “I’m dead, I’m dead, I’m glad I’m dead!” as he believes he’s in heaven.

Could also be referring to Fahrenheit 451, except that book’s main character is a young man. (Also by Bradbury.).

This is a recurring theme in post apocalyptic science fiction.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  "Jack in the Box" is interesting as a story of a socially-isolated person, but it doesn't really fit the part of the question that has people (multiple) interacting remotely via screens.  Not a bad answer, though it doesn't really look like "Jack in the Box" and "The Fireman" were ever printed in the same collection.

Comment: I thought that a reader might have conflated the two Bradbury stories, as the screens are an important element of farenheit 451.  Also in F 451, a girl enjoys being outdoors and remarks upon the beauty.

Comment: I guessed that's why you mentioned the two, and why I noted that I couldn't find evidence that they had been collected together, which is the normal reason that someone might conflate them.

Comment: …or because both are futuristic Ray Bradbury stories, with consistent styles and dystopian theme…